# What is the use of the last argument on this template function?

Tags: c++, templates

On a book about C++ I have found following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> T sum(T* b, T* e, T init = T()) {
    while(b != e)
    init += *b++;
    return init;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    cout << sum(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof a[0]) << endl; // 6
}
```

What is the use of the last argument of my template function `T init = T()`?
The author says the following about the third argument:

> The third argument to **sum( )** is the initial value for the accumulation
>   of the elements.

But how can this work? Isn't it a bad habit to have 3 arguments but only use the first two of them? Does this work for all types or in other words, is `T()` defined in the C++ standard for all datatypes?

Note: I know from testing that it initialize `init` to `0`.

Comment: it is a default argument. Providing 2 arguments is valid as long as `T` is default constructible.

Comment: The default argument is only evaluated at instantiation time, so there's no need for `T()` to be defined for all types. It only needs to be defined for those types for which you instantiate the template and use the default argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last argument is the initial value, I'd say. The idea is probably that you can continue a sum or that it is not clear what the zero element is.

Parameters like this are so called default parameters and quite usual. Like for example, if you'd made your own vector class:

```
template <class T>
Vector(const unsigned int size, const T& default_value = (T) 0);
```

You can then create a Vector object either by one parameter or by two, `Vector<double> vector(2);` or `Vector<double> vector(2, 5.);`. First call produces a vector of size 2 that is all zero, second call a vector of size 2 with all entries being 5.

In your example, you can add something to the sum.

In your case, the standard constructor is called, which is probably assumed to be a zero element.

That said, if your book tends to work with pointer arithmetics and has the habit of first leaving out {}-brackets and then not even use indentation where they are omitted, I'd recommend another book.

Comment: `T()` is bettern than `(T) 0`. `Vector<Vector<std::string>>` is invalid in your case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah yeah, I agree. Won't edit nonetheless, is more readable that way for the sake of explaining things, even if it will only work with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [value initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), which gives it a default value.

Roughly, for value initialisation, if T is a built-in type, then it is zero-initialised, if it is a class type, then the default constructor will be called.

The third parameter is for such usage:

```
cout << sum(a, std::end(a), 12) << endl; // 18
```

Answer (score 2):

> But how can this work?

As others have said, the third argument will be default constructed, or in the case of primitives (like `int`), it will be calling the free-floating function that will create, initialize, and return one with a value of `0`.

> Isn't it a bad habit to have 3 arguments but only use the first two of them?

Not necessarily. I mean, default arguments exist in most languages. It helps keep the amount of typing and mental overhead down. Besides, sometimes the developer does know a "good" default value for an argument. In the case of summation, usually people want to start with `0`, and usually the summation is called over primitives.

> Does this work for all types or in other words, is T() defined in the C++ standard for all datatypes?

No it is not. You could create an arbitrary type that must be constructed with some parameters. In such a scenario you are forced to provide the third argument yourself. For example:

```
struct IntHolder
{
    int value = 0;
    IntHolder(int _init) : value(_init){}
    IntHolder& operator+=(const IntHolder& other)
    {
        value += other.value;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<class T> T sum(T* b, T* e, T init = T()) {
    while(b != e)
    init += *b++;
    return init;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<IntHolder> a{1,2,3};
    cout << sum(a.data(), a.data()+a.size(), IntHolder(0)).value << endl; // 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very useful feature of specifying the generic argument this way is that the same code can apply to non-numeric types, provided they support a default constructor and `operator+=` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class T> T sum(T* b, T* e, T init = T()) {
    while(b != e)
        init += *b++;
    return init;
}

int main() {
    std::string a[] = { "the ", "cat ", "sat ", "on ", "the ", "mat" };
    std::cout << sum(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof a[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

However, the author ought to have implemented the generic function in terms of iterators, as it would have been less restrictive:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <array>

//
// better - now works with all forward iterator models, including pointers
//
template<class Iter, class T = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>
T sum(Iter b, Iter e, T init = T()) {
    while(b != e)
        init += *b++;
    return init;
}

int main() {
    std::string a[] = { "the ", "cat ", "sat ", "on ", "the ", "mat" };
    std::cout << sum(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof a[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sum(std::begin(a), std::end(a)) << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> vi = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << sum(std::begin(vi), std::end(vi)) << std::endl;

    std::array<int, 6> ai = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    std::cout << sum(std::begin(ai), std::end(ai)) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this third argument you can specify the initial amount of the accumulation. Try this:

```
cout << sum(a, a + sizeof a / sizeof a[0], 10); //16
```

Answer (score 0):

How would you write a (trivial) sum of array of ints? Probably like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) sum = sum+t[i];
```

More "generically" if you have an array of `T`s (with appropriate operators `+`,`=`):

```
T sum = T();
for (int i=0; i<l; i++) sum = sum+t[i];
```

Of course what you need (to be slightly more generic) is to provide any first (initial) value you want for the `sum`. This is why the third argument exists with a **default** value that lets you ignore it.

Not all classes provides a ctor callable with no parameter, but there exists the concept of **canonical** class among C++ informal rules of programming, for which you have to provide a ctor callable with no parameter, thus the default value.